# How to remap escape, tilde, and quotes on 21.10 with xkb options

Tags: kubuntu, xkb, remapping

I would like to swap the backtick/tilde key with escape and also single and double quotes by creating new options to be picked up.

I already have caps lock and left control swapped as well as parens and brackets in Kubuntu since there were options.

Comment: @guiverc typo fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disappointing as this answer may be, but you cannot. You can change the xkb options that are available, but you cannot do other things which are not exposed through the xkb options.

That can be done with `xmodmap`, but unfortunately, that tool is not always reliable in modern desktop environments. It may stop working after you put your computer to sleep, or if you attached a different keyboard or switched to a different keyboard layout (e.g. different language).

So it cannot be done with xkb options, and using xmodmap has its issues. The only way this can be changed is by customizing a keyboard layout.

Comment: Thanks. That kind of sucks. If I were interest in creating a new option or two, do you know what project that would be? Hopefully it would work for Wayland and X?

Comment: Customizing the keyboard layout is quite more complicated than changing xkb options (which is what you asked here), but it can be done editing keyboard layout files: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Using .Xmodmap should do the trick. The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xmodmap) has a good description on how to configure your keyboard.
Basically you have to create a file name `.Xmodmap` in your home directory.
`xmodmap -pke`will list your existing mapping, with `xev` you can check your keycodes. With the gathered information the entries could look like this:

```
!caps to super
clear lock
keycode 66 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_R

!Map Pause to Mic Mute
keycode 127 = XF86AudioMicMute NoSymbol XF86AudioMicMute
```

The first example maps the caps lock to the super key, the second one a "pause" key is used to toggle my mic.

After saving your settings restart (logout/login)

Comment: I thought you were not supposed to use xmodmap anymore. I'm not even sure it is even read. One of the reasons I wanted to use xkb options was also the ability to turn it off and on. thanks though.

Comment: That is correct: xmodmap may work, but may then stop after you put computer in sleep mode, switch keyboard layouts or keyboard, etc. There are indeed xkb options, but you can only change the options that are available. For aspects not included in these options, you will need to edit keyboard layouts directly.

Comment: Thats what I like being in this forum. Using this solution for many years I won't be surprised if it suddenly stops working now. Thanks for clearing this up